# Linux is not showing correct hdd name

Tags: linux

In my system when I attach my USB HDD, it is showing it as `sdc` instead of `sdb`. I do not have any other HDD attached.

```
[root@localmirror ~]# ls /sys/block/
dm-0/ dm-1/ dm-2/ sda/  sdc/  sr0/
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: Can you provide more outputs? i.e: `ls /dev/sd*`, `dmesg`, `mount`... when the device is attached

Comment: Search for `sdb` in  `/var/log/messages`.

Answer (score 2):

`/dev/sdx` is not the "correct hdd name", and you never should rely on a specific device node, especially for removable devices. You usually can rely on the UUID of the device/partition, or on the file system label (if any).

In `/etc/fstab`, instead of `/dev/sdx` you can specify `UUID=` or `LABEL=`

Additionally, there should be entries in `/dev/disk/by-uuid` and eventually `/dev/disk/by-label`, which should be links to the actual device nodes. So, for manual access, you may mount`/dev/disk/by-uuid/<UUID>` od `/dev/disk/by-label/<LABEL>`. To find out UUID and/or LABEL, just do `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid` and `ls -l /dev/disk/by-label`.

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple of ideas:
1- `sdb` device is in reality the `dm` one
2- `sdb` device was created (before `sdc` detection) and then destroyed (after the `sdc` detection)

Further reading: I suggest you reading some documentations if you have not yet done it
e.g. http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition-Mass-Storage-Definitions-Naming-HOWTO/x99.html
http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition/devices.html